# Semantic linefeeds (one sentence per line) in Emacs

Tags: latex, auctex, version-control

I'm trying to get Emacs to insert a line break at the end of each sentence as I type. (Why? Makes for easier version control of `tex` files.)

Looking around I found a few places with some suggestions for how to do something similar.

- [This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539984/how-do-i-get-emacs-to-fill-sentences-but-not-paragraphs) answers are mostly suggestions for how to take a document and insert line breaks after each sentence after the fact.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865975/emacs-abbreving-to-ending-sentence) is asking for a slightly different feature, viz. having Emacs insert two spaces after each sentence.

In an answer to the second question, abo-abo suggests something like this:

```
(defun electric-space ()
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back "\\w\\.")
      (insert " "))
  (self-insert-command 1))

(defvar electric-space-on-p nil)

(defun toggle-electric-space ()
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key
   " "
   (if (setq electric-space-on-p
             (not electric-space-on-p))
       'electric-space
     'self-insert-command)))
```

A small change to this almost allows me to do what I want: replace `insert "  "` with `insert "%\n"`. One downside of this is that the point always ends up on the second column of the following line. Thus, this is what results if I call `toggle-electric-space`:

```
Hello world. %
 This is another line.
```

Is there an obvious way around this?

Another problem with this approach is that there are cases where `.` does not come at the end of a sentence (though that's easy to fix by writing, e.g. `p.~23` instead of `p. 23`, which is good practice anyway) as well as cases where a sentence ends with something other than a period (`?`, `!`, `.)`, etc.).

Now, it seems to me that these problems should be easy to get around in Emacs, since we have something like `forward-sentence` around, which is smart enough as far as I can tell to recognize that `(This sentence.)` ends after the closing parenthesis. But I don't know how to make use of `forward-sentence` in combination with the definition of `electric-space` above.

[This package](https://github.com/jeeger/twauctex/) manages to do something similar to what I want. The difference is that it makes `.` electric, so it requires explicitly listing all the possible exceptions, i.e. all cases where a period does not end a new line. And in order to allow for sentences that do not end with a period, the package makes `?` and `!` electric, but I see no easy way of allowing for `.)` and `?)`, etc., to be recognized as ending sentences.

I suppose adding a condition like `if (looking-back ".")` in making the closing parenthesis electric might work... I'll need to study that package more careful and see how I could modify it to suit my purposes. But being effectively a `lisp` illiterate, I'd appreciate any pointers you may have.

## Update

The way to implement abo-abo's suggestion should instead be this:

```
(defun electric-space () ; Trying to get Emacs to do semantic linefeeds
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back (sentence-end))
      (insert " %\n")
       (self-insert-command 1))
       )

(defvar electric-space-on-p nil)

(defun toggle-electric-space ()
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key
   " "
   (if (setq electric-space-on-p
             (not electric-space-on-p))
       'electric-space
     'self-insert-command)))
```

I don't know if there's a more elegant way to do this, but for now it seems to work.

Comment: Docstring of function `sentence-end`: The default value specifies that in order to be recognized as the end of a sentence, the ending period, question mark, or exclamation point must be followed by two spaces, with perhaps some closing delimiters in between.

Comment: But this can be overridden, I believe, setting `sentence-end-double-space` to `nil`, no?

Comment: It seems, yes.  Something like (looking-back (sentence-end)) should tell if point it at end of sentence.  However, it seems to return t as soon as last char is a `.`.

Comment: Instead of electric, you could add to post-self-insert-hook a function that tests if point is at end of sentence and inserts a newline if so.

Comment: It seems you have found a working solution, so post it as an answer and accept it ;)

Comment: @Xerus done! I had forgotten about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting the 'update' to my question here as an answer.)

The way to implement abo-abo's suggestion should instead be this:

```
(defun electric-space () ; Trying to get Emacs to do semantic linefeeds
  (interactive)
  (if (looking-back (sentence-end))
      (insert " %\n")
       (self-insert-command 1))
       )

(defvar electric-space-on-p nil)

(defun toggle-electric-space ()
  (interactive)
  (global-set-key
   " "
   (if (setq electric-space-on-p
             (not electric-space-on-p))
       'electric-space
     'self-insert-command)))
```

I don't know if there's a more elegant way to do this, but for now it seems to work.

That said, since asking this question, the package [twauctex](https://github.com/jeeger/twauctex) has [changed](https://github.com/jeeger/twauctex/commit/1471c17e9544a85da7233994bbda158ffbf68982#diff-6ab1bcb77d070e6df605a4b9d05bf0a1403988e7398464ac2c3e8e61837dc6dd) and now uses and makes `SPC` electric rather than `.`. I've been happily using this package for a while now and highly recommend it to other `auctex` users.

Comment: that function should work in any mode though, right? On the other hand the plugin is only for auctex - so I could use the function in org mode as well.

Comment: I don't see why not!

Comment: This does not work